# ССП, запятая или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Сегодня мы должны понимать, что Россия — это общий дом для всех населяющих ее территорию народов(,) и вклад каждого из них заслуживает объективной оценки в научных трудах.
Вроде запятая в скобках нужна, но сомневаюсь (у автора нет).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сегодня мы должны понимать, что Россия — это общий дом для всех населяющих ее территорию народов и вклад каждого из них заслуживает объективной оценки в научных трудах

**Это СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными,** связанными одиночным союзом И, поэтому запятая не ставится. В данном случае главная часть явно относится к обоим придаточным.

Comment: Не могли бы разъяснить подробнее?

Comment: Если поставить запятую, то у нас будет другая конструкция: СПП с одним изъяснительным придаточным, далее союз И, далее самостоятельное предложение. То есть это будет сложное предложение с подчинительной и сочинительной связью. Но в этом случае третье предложение должно быть самостоятельным, не имеющим тесной связи со вторым предложением, чтобы мы не считали их однородными придаточными.

Comment: Не могли бы выделить главную часть и остальные?  Извините за непонятливость.

Comment: (1) Сегодня мы должны понимать, что (2) Россия — это общий дом для всех населяющих ее территорию народов и (3) вклад каждого из них заслуживает объективной оценки в научных трудах. Предложение (1) является главным по отношению к однородным придаточным (2) и (3). Но если поставить запятую, то оно будет главным только по отношению к придаточному (2)

Comment: Спасибо большое!